# Cannot access Google API Client?

Tags: java, android, string, api, google-maps

I've implemented `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` in my project (as well as it's three callback methods `onConnected`, `onConnectionSuspended`, &  `onConnectionFailed`), **but I am unable to reference the Google Location API Client!**

[image] (c is just an object that holds context)

**I've tried changing the parameters into `this`, `volumeContentObserver.this`, and even holding context in a variable beforehand and referencing it in the parameter of the API Client.**

### None of these options worked. How can I properly reference my GoogleApiClient?

P.S., here is the full class declaration:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
public class volumeContentObserver extends ContentObserver implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
```

---

And here's the problem code:

```
 if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(c)
                                        .addConnectionCallbacks(volumeContentObserver.this)
                                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(volumeContentObserver.this)
                                        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                                        .build()
                                        .connect();// Connecting the client
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your're assigning connect response, which returns void to mConnectApiClient,if your want to connect do like this:

```
   if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(c)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(volumeContentObserver.this)                                              .addOnConnectionFailedListener(volumeContentObserver.this)
    .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `connect()` at the end which returns `void` not a instance of `GoogleApiClient`.

Try this:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(c)
                           .addConnectionCallbacks(volumeContentObserver.this)
                           .addOnConnectionFailedListener(volumeContentObserver.this)
                           .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                           .build();                                        
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I did you should try this code, hope this work for you

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
}
```

Before this you must define gooleAiClient.connect(); in onStart metod.